# Somar linha em matriz

Tags: php-7

Implementei esse código para somar  linha por linha da matriz e dizer qual linha possui maior soma, porem a saida está em branco, no caso a soma seria da linha 1 (1+1+1+1) linha 2 (0+1+0+1) e assim por diante. alguem pode me ajudar?

```
  <?php
  $matriz = array
  (
   array(1, 0, 0, 1),
   array(1, 1, 1, 0),
   array(1, 0, 1, 1),
   array(1, 1, 1, 1)
 );
 $sum = 0;
 $no = 0;
 foreach ($matriz as $array){
    if(($sum += $array[$no])>$sum+=$array[$no+1]){
        echo "a linha de maior soma é =  $array[no]";
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Você quer somar a coluna, então, certo? e não a linha...

Comment: Olá jassRiver, tentei representar uma matriz quadrada nesse código, no caso somaria as linhas, como no código seria as linha 1 1 1 1, 0 1 0 1, 0 1 1 1, 1 0 1 1.

Comment: Peço desculpas, não lembrava da nomenclatura usada nas matrizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tente isso:

```
<?php

$matriz = array(
    array(1, 10, 3, 50),
    array(1, 10, 3, 50),
    array(1, 10, 3, 50),
    array(1, 10, 3, 50),
    array(1, 10, 3, 50)
);

$num_lines = count($matriz);
$num_elem_per_line = count($matriz[0]);
$maior = 0;
$maiorSoma = 0;
$soma = 0;

// Linha
for( $linha = 0; $linha <= ($num_elem_per_line-1); $linha++ ) {
    // Coluna
    for( $coluna = 0; $coluna <= ($num_lines-1); $coluna++ ) {    
        // Soma os elementos da linha
        $soma += $matriz[$coluna][$linha];
    }
    // verifica se a soma atual é maior que a maior soma já registrada
    if ( $soma > $maiorSoma ) {
        $maior = $linha+1; // $linha é indice, logo, começa por 0, por isso +1
        $maiorSoma = $soma;
    }
    // Reinicia a soma da soma para zero
    $soma = 0;
}

echo "A linha de maior soma é: $maior <br>";
echo "A maior soma é: $maiorSoma";
?>
```

---

O algoritmo não irá aceitar que uma próxima coluna seja a maior soma se ela tiver a mesma quantidade de elementos, como no seguinte exemplo:

```
$matriz = array(
    array(1, 10, 3, 5, 10),
    array(1, 10, 3, 5, 10),
    array(1, 10, 3, 5, 10),
    array(1, 10, 3, 5, 10),
    array(1, 10, 3, 5, 10)
);
```

Nesse caso, o algoritmo irá apontar que a maior linha é a segunda.
Pra mudar isso, é só colocar `>=` ali no **IF**

---

*Só funciona com matrizes que tem todas as colunas com quantidade iguais de elementos*
**Não funciona no seguinte exemplo:**

```
$matriz = array(
    array(1, 10, 3, 50, 100),
    array(1, 10, 3, 50),
    array(1, 10, 3, 50),
    array(1, 10, 3, 50),
    array(1, 10, 3, 50)
);
```

Comment: obrigado amigo.